# Netplan, networkd, resolvconf conflicts: Can't change DNS servers

Tags: networking, server, dns, netplan, resolvconf

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a headless server and trying to change the DNS that the server uses. I set up the netplan .yaml file like this to use Cloudflare's servers:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32
        - xxxx.xxxx.xxx::2/64
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
        - to: ::/0
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1111
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1001
```

After a `sudo netplan apply`, everything seemed copasetic. Except `nslookup somewebsite.com` showed that the DNS used was 8.8.8.8.

I traced the source of this, I think, to the /etc/resolv.conf file, which is not a symbolic link and which looks like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual #nameservers.
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Not only does that file say that it's not to be edited, it in fact can't be edited. And I'm sure that, if I were to edit it, it would be overwritten (by resolvconf, I assume) with that Google nameserver.

I'm now in a position where everything checks out except the actual DNS being used, which is stubbornly stuck on 8.8.8.8.

For example, `sudo networkctl status enp0s31f6` returns this:

```
● 2: enp0s31f6                                                                       
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s31f6.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                  Online state: online                                               
                          Path: pci-0000:00:1f.6
                        Driver: e1000e
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
                    HW Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Fujitsu Technology Solutions GmbH)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9000)
                         QDisc: pfifo_fast
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: 1Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: tp
                       Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                                xxxx:xxx:xx:xxxx::2
                                xxxx::xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx
                       Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                                xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                                fe80::1
                           DNS: 1.1.1.1
                                1.0.0.1
                                2606:4700:4700::1111
                                2606:4700:4700::1001
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab11edfd2edd2491a9410000
```

And `sudo resolvctl status` gives this:

```
    Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.0.0.1

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001

Link 8 (wg0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

So everything I look at tells me that 1.1.1.1 is the primary DNS for my server. Except `nslookup askubuntu.com` which stubbornly always returns this:

```
    Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
```

I verified that 8.8.8.8 is indeed being used by running `sudo tcpdump -n -vv -i enp0s31f6 -W 1200 | grep google.com` in one window while running `nslookup google.com` in another.

How can I get my server to stop using 8.8.8.8 and start using the DNS I've been trying to get it to run?

Comment: Welcome, is your `systemd-resolved.service active` and running? `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is running.

Comment: if I look at 22.04.1 (server and  desktop), there is `/etc/resolv.conf` a link to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. somehow your system is tainted  there.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what most people have. I'm not at all sure why I have an actual file instead of a symlink.

Comment: Do you have the resolvconf package installed?

Comment: (the comments in /etc/resolv.conf suggest that you do.)  Anyway, resolvconf is deprecated, and you should remove it from your system.  If you installed it: why?

Comment: I see from the logs that I did install it but I have no idea why or as part of what. I have since managed to get things working by changing the attributes on /etc/resolv.conf, deleting it and replacing it with a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. I would like to uninstall resolvconf, but fear doing so will mess things up....

Comment: Just realized why and how resolvconf got installed on my system. It was installed by the script I used to configure wireguard. I figured this out when wireguard no longer worked after I removed resolvconf. The fix for that was just to comment out the DNS line in wg0.conf.